# Insane Mod_Rewrite - code in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, document

I'd like to write simple rewrites on my website using htaccess file.

From ---> http:// www.mydomain.com/404.html
to        --->  http:// www.mydomain.com

From ---> http:// www.mydomain.com/505.html
to        --->  http:// www.mydomain.com

the same thing for the page 403.html/500.html and some like these pages (i thought that i could use a RegExp(s), but I tried to do it without success).

Another thing that i can't do it is:
From ---> http:// www.mydomain.com/done/everything_that_is_writes_after_this_slash
to       --->  http:// www.mydomain.com/done

Can someone help me, please? I'm going mad for this mod_rewrite!

Ps If i've an associate domain, e.g *http:// www.mydomainassociate.com* wherethrough i just buy a redirect service (without possibility to configure the htaccess file). 
If someone write in the browser "*http:// www.mydomainassociate.com/**about**/*", Is it possible redirect this URL to "*http:// www.mydomain.com/**about**/*", please? Is it possible to do that by htaccess file of *http:// www.mydomain.com/*, please?

Thanks for the patience!
Thanks for the attention!
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the error page redirect as simple as

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/[0-9]{3}.html$  / [NC,L]
```

[0-9] means "any digit" and {3} means "exactly three times".  NC means case-insentive so it'll match .HTML as well as .html.  L means it's the last rule it needs to process, there's no point checking for any other redirects.  The ^ and $ mark the beginning and end of the page, so it'll ONLY match /123.html, and not /bob/123.html.

And the second one

```
RewriteRule ^/done/  /done [NC,L]
```

(though if you actually wanted it to go to "/done/" (with the trailing slash) change it to

```
RewriteRule ^/done/.+  /done/ [NC,L]
```

to avoid a redirect loop.  The "." means "any character", and the + means "one or more times".

For the last bit of your question, you can't redirect pages from mydomainassociate.com via an .htaccess file on mydomain.com.  Unless the two domains are on the same hosting/root, in which case the question makes no sense?

Comment: Oh, and if you want those pages to be a redirect (so the URL changes in the user's browser), then add R=301 into the square brackets at the end of the rule.

Comment: Thank you for your help... But if the web hosting provider doesn't support this line "Options +FollowSymlinks", how can i do? This web hosting provider is Aruba, in fact all forums said that "you have to commentate this line (# Options +FollowSymlinks)" ...I think that i go to name.com or godaddy.com -.-''

Comment: You may find that it works without that line.  Try it, if you haven't already.

Comment: This is my .htaccess file:  ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mydomain.com/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/404.html
ErrorDocument 505 http://www.mydomain.com/505.html
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.mydomain.com/500.html

# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/[0-9].html$  / [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: You missed the {3} bit out of the last line.

Comment: I know, but w/ {3} is the same story...it doesn't work... However thank you

Comment: If you're trying to rewrite all of those error pages to root, why not just set ErrorDocument 403 index.html ErrorDocument 404 index.html ErrorDocument 500 index.html, etc.  Rather than specifying separate error pages and then trying to rewrite them all to index.html?